# How to make this traveler stay on the same level curve while traveling on $z=f(x,y)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> A traveler is standing on the point $(1,-3,e)$ on a mountain that is defined by the function: $z=f(x,y)=e^{11-x^2-y^2}$. He decided to move from there in a direction that lets him stay on the same level curve of the mountain. 
> In which direction in the space should he move?

My thoughts: 
Level curves remind me of the gradient vector, since $\vec \nabla f$ is perpendicular to the level curve of $f$. 
So my idea is to find a direction such that $\vec \nabla f(x,y)$ will stay equal to $\vec \nabla f(1,-3)$ (the given point). 
So first of all I found: 
$\vec \nabla f(1,-3)=(-2e,6e)$. 

But here, I'm not sure how to continue, I want to somehow make the function have this gradient always for the direction I will choose, and I'm not sure how to do that or if I'm thinking nonsense. 
Would really appreciate any help or feedback. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The direction should be orthogonal to $\nabla f(1,-3)$...

Comment: @DanielHuff Thanks! That makes sense, could I get a hint on how to deal with having $2$ variables? like if $(-2e,6e)\cdot (a,b)=0$, There must be something else that I need to know about the direction and I'm missing it...

Comment: @DanielHuff I think I understand now, them asking for a direction doesn't mean there is only one vector pointing in that direction, and from knowing what you said I can see that the vector is $(3b, b)$, but I'm struggling to connect that to the space, I really want to say $(3b,b,0)$ is the direction, but I'm unsure of why is that correct or the logic behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A level curve of $z = f(x,y)$ is the curve of points $(x,y)$ where $z$ is some constant value.

In this case,

$z = f(x,y) = e^{11-x^2-y^2} = e \implies x^2+y^2 = 10$

You can parametrize the level curve as $r(t) = (\sqrt{10} \cos t, \sqrt{10} \sin t, e)$

$r'(t) = (- \sqrt{10} \sin t, \sqrt{10} \cos t, 0)$

So at point $(1, -3, e)$, the direction should be $(\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}, 0)$.

Comment: Thanks alot, I understood the steps, and the parametrization of the circle in the space, taking derivative would always give a direction which makes the traveler stay on the same circle, but I didn't quite get the last line, how did you calculate it in the point?

Comment: At the given point $P$, $r(t_1) = (1, -3, e) = (\sqrt{10} \cos t_1, \sqrt{10} \sin t_1, e) \implies \sqrt{10} \cos t_1 = 1, \sqrt{10} \sin t_1 = -3$ so $r'(t_1) = (3, 1, 0)$. I just normalized it to state the direction.

Comment: $r'(t_1) = (- \sqrt{10} \sin t_1, \sqrt{10} \cos t_1, 0)$ so I just plug in values of $\cos t_1$ and $\sin t_1$ from above. I hope it is clear.

Comment: Thanks alot, now it's all clear, if I could trouble you to look at the comments under the question where Daniel Huff gave a hint that it should be perpendicular to the gradient vector, I got the same direction as you as a vector in $2d$, and wasn't sure about the third component if it's $0$ or not. Now I could say it's $0$ because the line curve we got was a circle that is "parallel" to xy plane, if it had some ups and downs (in $z$ direction), I couldn't infer that the third component is $0$. is what I said correct?

Comment: @Pwaol yes what you say is correct. The important thing is to see that a level curve of $z = f(x,y)$ would mean $z = c$ where $c$ is a constant. In this case it is $e$. Also on the other point, gradient vector is normal to the tangent plane at $P$ and tangents to level curves passing through $P$ will be perpendicular to the gradient vector at $P$. In other words, tangents to level curves at $P$ are contained in the tangent plane.